# Text becomes invisible when i update textfield.text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I have tried googling for so long now, but I cannot find the solution for this problem.

I have a textfield, with 3 strings and 3 variables. When the variables change I want the textField to display the updated version of the variables, so I use textfield.text = "newly updated text" but then the text is not visible. After the update event triggers, the text "disappears", but it's still there If I trace(textField.text) it outputs the right info. I have embedded the text aswell. 
Any help is deeply appreciated

```
public var infoBox:TextField = new TextField  ;
public var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat;

     myFormat.color = 0xAA0000;
        myFormat.size = 30;
        myFormat.font = "Font1";
        myFormat.italic = false;
        myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.LEFT;
        infoBox.text = "BonusbonusDamage:  " + bonusDamage + "\nFlame:  " + flame + "\nSticky" + sticky;
        infoBox.type = "dynamic";
        infoBox.width = 300;
        infoBox.height = 150;
        infoBox.border = true;
        infoBox.borderColor = 0xFFFFFF;
        infoBox.background = true;
        infoBox.backgroundColor = 0x000000;
        infoBox.wordWrap = true;

        infoBox.setTextFormat(myFormat);

        infoBox.x = 25;
        infoBox.y = 20;
        addChild(infoBox);

public function updateText()
    {

        infoBox.text = "BonusbonusDamage:  " + bonusDamage + "\nFlame:  " + flame + "\nSticky" + sticky;
```

This is where the text becomes invisible, even thoug its .visible is true and .alpha Is 100.

```
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `infobox.embedFonts = true;` as your `Font1` is apparently an embedded font. This is a pretty known issue with custom fonts in a text field.

[`TextField.embedFonts` manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#embedFonts)

EDIT: Yep, you are using `setTextFormat()` and this format is cleared whenever you replace `text` property. Use `defaultTextFormat` property instead.

```
infoBox.defaultTextFormat=myFormat;
```

Comment: If anyone helped you with a proper answer, you should "accept" that answer as correct, so that other people will see it and use it too. Use the "tick" on the left of an answer to accept it.